# Complex printf()

Tags: c, function, printf

I'm creating a simple menu and I've got stucked.
I have a very repetitive code, in fact, the only thing that changes is the parameter of a printf(), so I want to create a function to call it. The problem comes when I need to take the arguments. I tried to read about variable arguments using header <stdarg.h>, and certainly I don't understant it, so I would just try to skip it. I mean, I would just need to pass the arguments coming directly to printf() with something like

```
lee(char* question,...) 
{
    /*some code*/
    printf(question,...);
    /*some code*/
}
```

if somebody can explain to me in an easy way how to accomplish it, please, because I don't think I need to process the multiple arguments.

Comment: It seems what you're looking for it [the `vprintf` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf), which requires you to learn about [*variadic functions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic). Especially lokkm at [the `vprintf` example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf#Example).

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to use `stdarg.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

lee(char* question, ...)
{
    va_list lst;
    va_start(lst, question);
    vprintf(question, lst);
    va_end(lst);
}
```

The `lst` variable stores information about the variable arguments. The macro `va_start()` is used to initialize it (the second parameter is the last non-variable argument). The macro `va_end()` is used to free the resources allocated by `va_start()`.

Normally, functions with variable arguments use `va_arg()` to get each argument, but here we just pass the list to `vprintf()` and it does that for us.

Comment: That's great. I would have liked a small explanation, but It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @IcaPolinesioGarLop Explanation added!